# How to run dbt_expectations tests only in specific database or target

Tags: dbt

We are adding some dbt_expectations tests to our project.
For example we run expect_table_row_count_to_be_between test.
Different values are expected on our limited dev environment and different on prod.
I want to turn off by default all the dbt_expectations tests from databases other than prod.

How can I do it?

I thought about tagging all test that should be skipped during the run on dev and then run something like:

```
dbt test -s some_model_name --exclude tag:whatever
```

But everyone would have to remember to add this --exclude tag:whatever in every operation.
I wander if there's a way to set this as default option, and when target name or dbase name is right (like: prod) dbt performs all tests.

I also tried to wrap dbt_expectations test into a generic test but it did not help.

```
{% if not skip_personalized or (skip_personalized and target.dbname in ['base_test', 'base_prod']) %}
{{ dbt_expectations.some_test() }}
{% else %} 
    select 1 where false -- make an empty table
{% endif %}
```

But this approach does not work. dbt_expectations is not recognized (yes, it is installed and tests in yaml files work)

Any idea?